# Conditional Links For Follow Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have self referential association working. My issue is that on users/show, I want to display different text depending on the users relationship with the current user.

Currently, I have it set to display nothing if the user = current user. If the user is not the current user and is not friends with the current user, I want to display a link to follow the user. Finally, if the user is not the current user and is already friends with the current user, I want to display text to say, "friends".

friendship.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

user.rb

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

users/show

```
<% unless @user == current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Follow", friendships_path(:friend_id => @user), :method => :post %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would define a method on the user model which we can use to determine if a user is friends with another user. That would look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def friends_with?(other_user)
    # Get the list of a user's friends and check if any of them have the same ID
    # as the passed in user. This will return true or false depending.
    friends.where(id: other_user.id).any?
  end
end
```

Then we can use that in the view to check if the current user is friends with a given user:

```
<% unless @user == current_user %>
  <% if current_user.friends_with?(@user) %>
    <span>Friends</span>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Follow", friendships_path(:friend_id => @user), :method => :post %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```